# Track [sh] <defunct> for debug purposes?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a big application (in C++), which generates from time to time defunct process. I know the application intensively uses linux commands inside. I would need to know which linux commands were called by those defunct sh process, is it possible to find out? Or, is it possible to set up Linux and get a sort of log when my application calls Linux commands?

Thanks.
Luke

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process):

> A defunct process is a process that
>   has completed execution but still has
>   an entry in the process table. This
>   entry is still needed to allow the
>   process that started the (now zombie)
>   process to read its exit status.

Is your C++ code calling `wait()`? If you get the exit status by calling `wait()` the defunct process should disappear.

Answer (score 3):

This big application is issuing external commands via a shell, using `popen` or similar library functions. The intermediate shells remain as zombies (“defunct processes”) because the application isn't calling [`wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) to “reap” its children. Note that zombie processes are totally harmless (no matter what B-movies might lead you to believe); the only resource they consume is an entry in the process table.

You can trace what commands the application executes by running

```
strace -f -s99999 -v -eexecve -o big-application.strace ./big-application
```

This may slow down your program somewhat. You can switch tracing on and off during the lifetime of a process: to start tracing, run

```
strace -f -s99999 -v -eexecve -o big-application.strace -p 12345
```

where 12345 is the process ID you want to trace. Kill the `strace` process (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) to stop tracing.